# Wrong conversion of time_t to char

Tags: arduino-mega

I have a simple sample of code that i want to convent a time_t to char array in order to concatenate it after, in an other array.
Code:

```
time_t unixt;
char exm [40];


unixt = RTC.get();
Serial.println(unixt);
dtostrf(unixt, 10, 0, exm);
Serial.println(exm);
```

The problem that i face is that, the console is printing different the second one every time like this:

```
1548258220
1548258200
```

I tried also with unsigned long with no result either. Can someone point me what's wrong or an other way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ultoa()` instead of `dtostrf()`. The former is meant to serialize
unsigned long integers, while the later is for floating point numbers.
By using `dtostrf()`, you are implicitly converting `unixt` to a
floating point number. The Arduino Mega only supports single precision
floating point, so this conversion incurs some loss of precision, hence
the result you see.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what i needed.